# CRC16 hash function that calculates hash value from two inputs

Tags: hash, xor, crc16

I want to write a CRC16 hash function that takes two inputs and generate a hash value from them. The current implementations calculate take only one input.

current:
    crc16(input_value)

required:
    crc16(input_value1, input_value2)

One solution can be calculating the hash value for each input separately and then xor them. However, I don't know what would be the effect on randomness. Is XORing enough, or I should take another approach?

Comment: [Cyclic Redundancy Check algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) process a sequence of bits and result in a hash signature. So, your "input_value" has to be a sequence of bits (or bytes). To process two inputs, you could concatenate them and thus combine them into one sequence. To calculate two hashes and `XOR` them into one should also be fine for practical purposes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll lose the properties of CRC this way. Why would you compute a CRC if you can't use it anyway? Note that CRC is not "just" a hash function, it is a very specific hash function for a very specific goal: it is an error correction and detection code. In particular, it is *not* a cryptographically secure hash function like SHA-3. In fact, it is easy *by design* to compute pre-images, length extensions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A more complete description of a CRC function would be:

```
new_crc_value = crc16(previous_crc_value, input_value)
```

Then to process two input values, you simply process them in sequence:

```
new_crc_value = crc16(crc16(previous_crc_value, input_value1), input_value2)
```